# Not able to fetch access token from reddit API using GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, reddit, http-status-code-400

I am trying to fetch the access token using obtained client ID and secret https://www.reddit.com/prefs/apps

The documentation is here: https://ads-api.reddit.com/docs/

The app name is "Reporting", this is selected as "web app" (I have no issues when script is chosen)

No matter what I try, I am getting {"message": "Bad Request", "error": 400}

I am implementing this using Apps script/Google Sheets

I have tried with

Auth URL:

> https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/authorize?client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxx&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fscript.google.com%2Fmacros%2Fd%2F1Nh3AKooeG8XH4rSTvEWLTf5l3Sgo3nPgK01qiusSany43fFNaUgg2q6b%2Fusercallback&state=ADEpC8xyajUigAfm1arE-N3gjrw-OLvI08gR23Y1ouQJpLpGtZ6ZPWTcpQRa8kW79ABqkxha1B8d90tb8B4eianNmJjFgzKzjCGwdxJ8lpDUdyNF7YjNq_3ak8d6Co_arPUDuP-BnbH0qRSwuEacP2Zif4wTt-YapR8VBbrkhr0tc6aScewnQPe9sCsOccRK6dITZ2SWFP_ZNA5rd03uP-f2HRJfMEoRMPFFLzvfYs9CvgDbzIopee4k_6jqiEg02zK_BuQSOijkUweB3oBTGpcQxHsU1QcRmXoXuzjucN8uF8M_MbWKhOhO-69g9rnKcHmH-Cto_hgnP8-53tn_ViCsqM2xf2dQ_w&scope=adsread%20history&duration=permanent

Redirect:

> https://script.google.com/macros/d/1Nh3AKooeG8XH4rSTvEWLTf5l3Sgo3nPgK01qiusSany43fFNaUgg2q6b/usercallback?state=ADEpC8xyajUigAfm1arE-N3gjrw-OLvI08gR23Y1ouQJpLpGtZ6ZPWTcpQRa8kW79ABqkxha1B8d90tb8B4eianNmJjFgzKzjCGwdxJ8lpDUdyNF7YjNq_3ak8d6Co_arPUDuP-BnbH0qRSwuEacP2Zif4wTt-YapR8VBbrkhr0tc6aScewnQPe9sCsOccRK6dITZ2SWFP_ZNA5rd03uP-f2HRJfMEoRMPFFLzvfYs9CvgDbzIopee4k_6jqiEg02zK_BuQSOijkUweB3oBTGpcQxHsU1QcRmXoXuzjucN8uF8M_MbWKhOhO-69g9rnKcHmH-Cto_hgnP8-53tn_ViCsqM2xf2dQ_w&code=m0PsSaLd1kKVZs7jymk1Qn69hXsTQw#_

Request

```
curl -X POST https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token \

-H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \

-A 'username' \

-u xxxxxxxxxxxxx:yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy \

-d 'grant_type=authorization_code&code=m0PsSaLd1kKVZs7jymk1Qn69hXsTQw#_&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fscript.google.com%2Fmacros%2Fd%2F1Nh3AKooeG8XH4rSTvEWLTf5l3Sgo3nPgK01qiusSany43fFNaUgg2q6b%2Fusercallback'
```

Response

```
{"message": "Bad Request", "error": 400}
```

Comment: Where is your apps script?

Answer (score 2):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- By accessing the authorization URL like `https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/authorize?client_id=CLIENT_ID&response_type=code&state=RANDOM_STRING&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URL&duration=DURATION&scope=SCOPE_STRING` with your browser, you want to retrieve the access token using Web Apps created by Google Apps Script.

In this case, the request of the following curl command is run by Google Apps Script by retrieving the authorization code.

```
 curl -X POST https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token \\
   -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \\
   -A 'CLIENT_NAME' \\
   -u CLIENT_ID:APP_SECRET \\
   -d 'grant_type=authorization_code&code=CODE&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URL'
```

In this case, how about the following sample script of Web Apps?

#### Sample script:

```js
function doGet(e) {
  const clientId = "###"; // Please set your client ID.
  const secret = "###"; // Please set your secret.
  const redirectUrl = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec"; // Please set your Web Apps URL that you are using it as the redirect URL.

  const url = "https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token";
  const params = {
    method: "post",
    headers: { "Authorization": "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(`${clientId}:${secret}`) },
    payload: {
      "code": e.parameter.code,
      "grant_type": "authorization_code",
      "redirect_uri": redirectUrl
    }
  };
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(res.getContentText());
}
```

- **After you set the variables in the script, please reflect the modified script to the Web Apps.**
- In this script, when you access your authorization URL of `https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/authorize?client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxx&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fscript.google.com%2Fmacros%2Fd%2F1Nh3AKooeG8XH4rSTvEWLTf5l3Sgo3nPgK01qiusSany43fFNaUgg2q6b%2Fusercallback&state=ADEpC8xyajUigAfm1arE-N3gjrw-OLvI08gR23Y1ouQJpLpGtZ6ZPWTcpQRa8kW79ABqkxha1B8d90tb8B4eianNmJjFgzKzjCGwdxJ8lpDUdyNF7YjNq_3ak8d6Co_arPUDuP-BnbH0qRSwuEacP2Zif4wTt- YapR8VBbrkhr0tc6aScewnQPe9sCsOccRK6dITZ2SWFP_ZNA5rd03uP-f2HRJfMEoRMPFFLzvfYs9CvgDbzIopee4k_6jqiEg02zK_BuQSOijkUweB3oBTGpcQxHsU1QcRmXoXuzjucN8uF8M_MbWKhOhO-69g9rnKcHmH-Cto_hgnP8-53tn_ViCsqM2xf2dQ_w&scope=adsread%20history&duration=permanent` and click "Arrow" button, the authorization code is sent to your Web Apps, and the access token and the refresh token are retrieved as follows.

  ```
    {"access_token": "###", "token_type": "bearer", "expires_in": 86400, "refresh_token": "###", "scope": "adsread history"}
  ```

### Note:

- In this modified script, it supposes that your function `batchArchiveEmail()` works fine. Please be careful about this.
- If you disable the V8 runtime, I thought that the script might be worked without the above modification. But in that case, the process cost of the loop will become high. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/3331e1e631d619abef8f32c4be14ba3a) By this, I would like to introduce this workaround.
- In this case, the setting of Web Apps is required to be `Execute as: Me` and `Who has access to the app: Anyone` for new IDE. Please be careful about this.

Comment: The problem is not the implementation of apps script, I am still getting the issue as  {"message": "Bad Request", "error": 400}

Comment: I can share the script. Could you please let me know your email @Tanaike ?

Comment: @Code Guy Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About `The problem is not the implementation of apps script, I am still getting the issue as {"message": "Bad Request", "error": 400}`, unfortunately, when I tested my proposed script the access token and refresh token are returned as I have already shown in my answer. I apologize that my proposed script worked. In your situation, for example, can you check whether your latest script of my proposed script is reflected in the Web Apps, again? And, can you check the URL of Web Apps again?

Comment: @Code Guy And also, can you confirm your client ID and secret and redirect URL, again? Even when you modify your current script to my proposed script, when the same error of `{"message": "Bad Request", "error": 400}` occurs, how about creating a new Google Apps Script project and test it using the new Web Apps URL and test it again? At that time, please update the redirect URL at the API side.

Comment: I think reddit ads API needs to be approved from the team for using it. The error is deceptive.

Comment: @Code Guy Thank you for replying. About `I think reddit ads API needs to be approved from the team.`, yes. When you access your URL for retrieving the authorization code and you authorize the scopes, the retrieved authorization code is sent to the Web Apps as the redirect. By this, script of Web Apps is run. And, access token and refresh token are returned. About `The error is deceptive.`, I cannot understand it. Can I ask you about the detail of it? By the way, when I tested my proposed script, no error occurs and the access token and refresh token are returned. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: @Code Guy From your question, I thought that you wanted to retrieve the access token and the refresh token by accessing the URL for retrieving the authorization code using a browser. If I misunderstood your goal, I apologize.